# ngrok error: Can't send test webhook from Stripe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments, webhooks, ngrok

I'm trying to send stripe webhook test `invoice.pyament_succeed` to local server with `ngrok`. Although `ngrok` would work, when sending webhook from stripe to it the error occurs:

```
POST /webhooks/stripe 500 Internal Server Error
```

I have setup `ngrok` and `stripe webhook` like below:
1. Setup `ngrok` on local server

```
 $ ngrok http 3000
```

It would work.

```
 Session Status                online                                                                                                                                                                        
 Account                       xxxxx (Plan: Free)                                                                                                                                                       
 Update                        update available (version 2.3.34, Ctrl-U to update)                                                                                                                           
 Version                       2.2.8                                                                                                                                                                         
 Region                        United States (us)                                                                                                                                                            
 Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                                                                                         
 Forwarding                    http://xxxx.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000                                                                                                                                    
 Forwarding                    https://xxxx.ngrok.io -> localhost:3000
```

2. Setup Stripe webhook

input the end point

```
 https://xxxxx.ngrok.io/webhooks/stripe
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
 Rails.application.routes.draw do  
   mount StripeEvent::Engine, at: '/webhooks/stripe'
 end
```

**config/stripe.rb**

```
 StripeEvent.configure do |events|
   # The case invoice payment succeed
   events.subscribe(
     'invoice.payment_succeed',
     Events::InvoicePaymentSucceed.new
   )
 end
```

Comment: Could you post more info? maybe the exception/error trace?

Comment: Sorry I have missed an error, and I had understood.